# Are the Informix and Lucene analyzers similar?

Tags: informix, elasticsearch

Is the analyzer discussed here same as Lucene analyzers? I am confused because most of them show similar properties to Lucene analyzer but the blog posts don't say a word about Lucene; instead they talk about something made by IBM called Informix.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=analyzers-snowball-analyzer

I just want to know about these 5 types of analyzer: stopword, simple, standard, whitespace and snowball. Are their properties the same as Lucene? It looks like they're same although their names aren't exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio) in a [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/315026/is-the-informix-and-lucene-analyzers-similar/315029#comment613949_315029), the Informix servers are documented to use CLucene as their analyzer technology in the Basic Text Search DataBlade.

- 12.10 [Basic Text Search](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=guide-basic-text-search)
- 14.10 [Basic Text Search](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=guide-basic-text-search)

Comment: This is explicitly stated [in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=guide-basic-text-search).

Comment: Thanks, @mustaccio — that helped.